# Challenges with letting another thread write data into Database (Android, java)

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, queue

In the Android application I'm working on, the object **Debt** represents one entry in the table **debts** within the database.

I have created a queue of objects of type **Debt** and a thread called **DatabaseWriter**. When I place a debt in this queue, the thread is awoken and takes care of creating a new entry in the database with the data contained in said **Debt** object.

*My problem is the following:*

1. The **Debt** object has to be written into the database before I can know its primary key (of type integer), which is set to autoincrement
2. At the same time, I am using the database primary keys to identify the **Debt** objects in the application. For example, I have HashMaps where the key will be the primary key inside the database and the value will be the **Debt** object in itself.

The conclusion is that I cannot update the database concurrently, because I can't use newly created **Debt** objects until I know their primary key in the database. With this model, the only possibility I am left with is doing everything sequentially.

Is there a way around this problem? What design patters are there to solve it? I am new with databases.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience in Android develop, but when using Mybatis and Mysql， you can use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` get the primary key immediately after insert the object. In this case, if you can not change the DB design, you can write a class named `IDGenerator` and it will do two things:

1. get the max id in the table when program startup and save in `AtomicLong` value called `nowId`
2. offer a method like `getId()`, this method just return `nowId.incrementAndGet()`